# Set Theory: supremum and infimum proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $B$ and $C$ be subsets of a partially ordered set $A$. Prove that if $supB=supC$, then $\upsilon(B)=\upsilon(C)$.

Here, $\upsilon(B)$ is the set of all upper bounds of $B$.

My attempt:

Suppose $supB=supC$

Call it $b=c$

$b \in \upsilon(B) \implies c \in \upsilon(C)$

$c \in \upsilon(C) \implies b \in \upsilon(B)$

Thus $\upsilon(B)=\upsilon(C)$

I think there is something wrong because $b$ and $c$ are not arbitrary elements. Can anyone help me out with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Aiming for a contradiction, assume that $x$ is in $v(B)$ but not in $v(C)$.

That is, $\forall b \in B: b \le x$, but $\exists c \in C:c > x$.

Then, $\sup b \le x$ and  $\sup c > x$, a contradiction.